# Change Facebook Messenger webhook url without FB re-reviewing application

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messages

Is it possible to change my Facebook Messenger webhook URL without having FB to review again my application (since it takes a couple of weeks to do so)?

Comment: I never tried to change url after getting FB review but I think it should be unrelated.

Comment: You are probably right, but we could not stand any downtime, which is the reason behind the question. In any case, I will test it next week and I share any results. Thnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can always change the webhook without having to resubmit your Facebook App for review. I've switch [my bot](https://github.com/hungtraan/FacebookBot)'s webhook back and forth several times (even to my local development webhook with `ngrok`).

In some apps the Webhooks is not even there yet, so for those who don't see it, you have to **"Add Product"** and choose **Webhooks**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation!